# Python 3 tkinter: dynamically set an element's state to "normal"?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, ttk

I'm pretty new to python, especially using tkinter. So far I have put together a ttk notebook with the help of this page http://www.pyinmyeye.com/2012/08/tkinter-notebook-demo.html.

What I am essentially asking is- can I dynamically set the second tab's *state* from "*disabled*" to "*normal*" when I press a ttk button in the first "*Welcome*" tab?

What the tabs are initially set to:

```
nb.add(frame, text='Welcome', underline=0, padding=2, state="normal")
nb.add(frame, text='Tab Two', underline=0, padding=2, state="disabled")
```

If it helps to put this into context, I am trying to make a pizza ordering program for a school project, and I want each step of the process in a different tab. I want the state of these tabs to depend on whether the pizzas are to be delivered or picked up; in which case some steps are not needed.
Thanks to anyone who even takes the time to read this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the state of a tab, use the [`tab`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.tab) method with the appropiate index and the options (in this case, the state). Since tabs are zero-index based, you should pass `1` to enable the second one:

```
nb.tab(1, state="normal")
```

You might also want to focus the corresponding tab. For that, you can use the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.select) method:

```
nb.select(1)
```